# How to optimize simple linked server select query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, performance, linked-server, openquery

I have a table called **Table** with columns:

- ID (int, primary key, clustered, unique index)
- TEXT (varchar 15)

on a MSSQL linked server called **LS**. Linked server is on the same server computer. And:

When I call:

```
SELECT ID, TEXT FROM OPENQUERY(LS, 'SELECT ID, TEXT FROM Table')
```

It takes **400 ms**.

When I call:

```
SELECT ID, TEXT FROM LS.dbo.Table
```

It takes **200 ms**

And when I call the query directly while being at LS server:

```
SELECT ID, TEXT FROM dbo.Table
```

It takes **100 ms**.

In many places i've read that OPENQUERY is faster, but in this simple case it does not seem to work. What can I do to make this query faster when I call it from another server, not LS directly?

Comment: I've only ever had to use OpenQuery when the linked server was of a different type, e.g Oracle. Is the difference always that marked ie. x2? If you were to send a bigger query requesting more data/heavier filter is the overhead as marked?

Comment: @CResults - when filter is  more complex ovehead is bigger, the difference is from several trials avg. Particular queries have very different times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `SELECT ID, TEXT FROM OPENQUERY(LS, 'SELECT ID, TEXT FROM dbo.Table')` to make the queries equivalent by using the schema?

Anyway, read this [article from Linchi Shea](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2009/07/21/performance-impact-linked-server-security-configuration-and-how-it-can-hurt-you.aspx) about linked servers

Note: a linked server call will always be slower than a direct call. From SQL Server to your SSMS is now going through another SQL Server instance first, so of course it will be slower.